# how to show the locale that the browser is showing in gwt I18N?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt-platform

i'm doing i18n to my application i did something that is shown in showcase example i'm using the listbox to show different locales, the problem is when i'm swapping from one locale to another locale,locale is changing but the list box is not showing the locale in which i am, it is showing first element of the list every time as it is reloading

here is code:

```
@Override
    public void changeSwap() {

    final String queryParam = LocaleInfo.getLocaleQueryParam(); 
    String locale=getView().getLocale().getValue(getView().getLocale().getSelectedIndex());
        Log.info("revealed locale is"+locale);
     if (queryParam != null) {
         UrlBuilder builder = Location.createUrlBuilder().setParameter(
             queryParam, locale);
         Window.Location.replace(builder.buildString());
       } else {
         // If we are using only cookies, just reload
         Window.Location.reload();
       }
    }
```

i didn't find any method in listbox api to do it

thanks

Comment: Post the code snippet that reproduces the problem

Comment: @Override
 public void changeSwap() {
  
 final String queryParam = LocaleInfo.getLocaleQueryParam(); 
 String localeFromView=getView().getLocale().getValue(getView().getLocale().getSelectedIndex());
  Log.info("revealed locale is"+localeFromView);
  if (queryParam != null) {
         UrlBuilder builder = Location.createUrlBuilder().setParameter(
             queryParam, localeFromView);
         Window.Location.replace(builder.buildString());
       } else {
         // If we are using only cookies, just reload
         Window.Location.reload();
       }
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a part of the code from the Showcase ([`ShowcaseShell.initializeLocaleBox()`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ShowcaseShell.java#322)), but the part that is responsible for selecting the correct value in the ListBox is this:

```java
String currentLocale = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
if (currentLocale.equals("default")) {
  currentLocale = "en";
}
String[] localeNames = LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames();
for (String localeName : localeNames) {
  if (!localeName.equals("default")) {
    String nativeName = LocaleInfo.getLocaleNativeDisplayName(localeName);
    localeBox.addItem(nativeName, localeName);
    if (localeName.equals(currentLocale)) {
      localeBox.setSelectedIndex(localeBox.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to add it to your code before adding the ChangeHandler to the localeBox.

---

Here's the full setup in the Showcase 2.4.0 example:

- [Showcase.gwt.xml 21-28](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/Showcase.gwt.xml#21) performs the locale setup for the module (especially it defines the available locales as "en", "ar", "fr", "zh")
- [ShowcaseShell.ui.xml 204-206](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ShowcaseShell.ui.xml#204) creates the ListBox widget.
- [ShowcaseShell.java 113-114, 190, 322-364](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ShowcaseShell.java#322) fill the available locales into the ListBox, and adds a ChangeHandler.

I would recommend to create a simple new GWT project (at first without gwtp or anything special) and just add these bits of code. Then you can try to migrate the setup to your full project.

Comment: actually i'm using gwtp and uibinder i've added two locales to my listbox like <g:item value="en">english</g:item>
 <g:item value="fr">french</g:item> and in my presenter i've added the logic, if add the code you specified here it is showing all the locales that r available in LocaleInfo but when i choose another locale the change is not happening is there any thing i'm missing

Comment: @krrish: 1.) You shouldn't add any `<g:item>`s manually at all. All locales that are defined in your `.gwt.xml` file (using <extend-property name="locale" values="fr"/>) are added to the box in the `for` loop. 2.) Then your `changeSwap()` method should do the change handling. You'll have to register it somehow as a ChangeHandler, but in your question you wrote, that the locale changing is already happening, so I assume you're already doing this (I hope you haven't removed that code)?

Comment: 1.if i remove '<g:item>' list is showing without any values in it and my changeSwap() it self is handler method which is called on onchange event.

Comment: if i keep <g:item> initially the list items from view are showing and when i reload it new list with all Locales is showing.thanks

Comment: could you just show me only those lines in which locale setup is done in showcase example

Comment: hi Chris thanks, it's working.i ignored setting up my view with new locale once the page is reloaded . and you are right it's not needed to add locales in listbox.

Comment: here i come up with another issue actually when i change my locale the page is entirely reloading, it should not be done. my app should use properties file at runtime it should simply change to new locale without reloading.